# Rename Files Based On Folder Name

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, rename, dos, prefix

I am using the following script to rename (prefix) files in subfolders with the string "Application".

```
pushd "%temporarydirectory%"
for /r %%j in (*) do (
rename "%%j" "Application - %%~nxj"
)
Popd
```

For example files in:

C:\temp\Lodgements\10 Smith Street

```
10001.doc
10002.doc
```

Are renamed to:

```
Application - 10001.doc
Application - 10002.doc
```

What I would like to do is to change the script so that files are renamed (prefixed) with the name of the folder in which they are contained. For example files in:

C:\temp\Lodgements\10 Smith Street

```
10001.doc
10002.doc
```

Are renamed to:

```
10 Smith Street - 10001.doc
10 Smith Street - 10002.doc
```

Regards

george Mackenzie kitten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pushd "%temporarydirectory%" && (
    for /r /d %%a in (.) do for %%b in ("%%~fa\*") do (
        echo ren "%%~fb" "%%~nxa - %%~nxb"
    rem Magoo's tickle begin
    echo "%%~nxb"|FINDSTR /l /c:"%%~nxa - " >NUL&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 echo ren "%%~fb" "%%~nxa - %%~nxb"
    rem Magoo's tickle end
    )
)
```

For each folder, for each file inside this folder, rename the file to the name and extension of the folder followed by the name and extension of the file

(noting that the `rename / ren` command is simply echoed for deomstration)

Magoo's tickle: Extends the proposed answer by removing the possibiity that a file named "10 Smith Street - 10001.doc" would be re-renamed "10 Smith Street - 10 Smith Street - 10001.doc" if the procedure was run more than once...

Comment: Thankyou MD ND excellent answer. Works like a treat. Thankyou also Magoo some good error trapping! :-)