# Add a suffix to filenames based on subfolder names within a directory in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, rename, pushd

I have a number of (sub)folders stored within a directory folder. Each subfolder contains 5-35 .jpg aerial photograph files that are named by flightline name and number (ie: bej-3-83). I would like to add a suffix to each of these files based upon the subfolder they are stored upon. For example if 'bej-3-83' is stored within 'T13N_10W' subfolder I would like my R script to rename 'bej-3-83' as 'bej-3-83-T13N_10W' and so forth for each file stored within each subfolder.

I can partially accomplish this process albeit still with more manual input than I'd like using this script:

```
folder = "C:\\...\\T23N_R14W"
files <- list.files(folder,pattern = "\\.jpg$",full.names = T) 
files
   sapply(files,FUN=function(eachPath){ 
   file.rename(from=eachPath,to= sub(pattern="_clip", paste0("_T23N_R14W"),eachPath))
 })
```

But as you can see this script uses a manual paste input of the subfolder name which isn't useful when you're trying to create a script that does what I need in one fell swoop.

I'm seeing similar questions and answers which utilize 'pushd' and 'popd' and I've attached to of those threads below as links. I'm trying to read as much as I can on these functions but so far the process to make it work has me stuck.

[How to rename files in folders to foldername using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266930/how-to-rename-files-in-folders-to-foldername-using-batch-file)

[Rename Files Based On Folder Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909445/rename-files-based-on-folder-name)

Sincerely,

Henry

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change the `dir_separator` to `\` on windows:

```
make_filename <- function(file_path) {
    s <- unlist(strsplit(file_path, dir_separator))
    fname <- gsub('\\.jpg$', '', s[length(s)])
    parent_dir <- s[(length(s) - 1)]
    new_fname <- paste0(parent_dir, "_", fname, '.jpg')
    path <- paste(s[-length(s)], collapse = dir_separator)
    return(paste(path, new_fname, sep = dir_separator))
}

folder = './data'
dir_separator = '/'
files <- paste0(folder, dir_separator, list.files(folder, recursive = T))
sapply(files, function(x) file.rename(from = x, to = make_filename(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive approach.

Pass the path to the root folder containing your files and the extension of the files you want to rename, to `rename_batch`.
Defaults are working directory and jpeg.

```
library(stringr)

# An auxiliary function
rename_file <- function(str, extra){
  file_name <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(str)
  file_ext <- tools::file_ext(str)
  return(paste0(file_name, '-', extra, '.', file_ext))
}

rename_batch <- function(path = "./",
                         extension = 'jpeg'){

  # Separate files from folders
  l <- list.files(path)
  files <- l[grepl(paste0("\\." , extension), l)]
  folders <- list.dirs(path, F, F)

  present_folder <- 
    stringr::str_extract(path, '(?<=/)([^/]+)$')

  # Check if there is a / at the end of path and removes it
  # for consistency
  path_len <- nchar(path)
  last <- substr(path, path_len, path_len)
  if (last == '/') {
    path <- substr(path, 1, path_len - 1)
  }

  if (length(files) > 0) {
    file_updtate <- paste0(path, '/', files)
    file.rename(file_updtate, rename_file(file_updtate, present_folder))
  }

  if (length(folders) > 0) {
  for (i in paste0(path, '/',  folders)) {
   cat('Renaming in:', i, '\n')
   rename_batch(i)
  }

  }    
}
```